# Is it possible to have bug in Webpage on same Bowers with same version but different OS(only desktop OS windows, mac,Ubuntu etc.)

Tags: testing, browser, html

One `Webpage(W)` running on `browser(B)` with `version(V)` and different desktop OS `OSX(OS-O)`, `Windows(OS-W)`, `Ubuntu(OS-U)` and etc.

```
W + B(V) + OS-O = OK
W + B(V) + OS-W = BUG or behave different from other OS
W + B(V) + OS-U = OK
```

I am not taking about browser bug. Here assume browser `B` don't have own internal bug.

give answer of this few questions.

1. above scenario possible or no
2. if yes then how and which situation
3. if no then why we still testing webpage for both OS with same browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and I've seen it happen a number of times.

For example, in most browsers scrollbars are different based on the OS. They are different sizes, and some take up content while others don't. If the webpage layout breaks because of this change, that may only happen on one OS. There's also the issue of macOS bouncy-scrolling and negative scroll positions.

Another example may be a difference in hotkeys. If you expect a user to be able to enter certain keys, but the OS captures them before they get to the page, you could have a problem.

Some browsers have different features based on the host OS. Some browsers depend on the host OS to supply video and audio codecs, which used to be a big issue when HTML5 video was new, but can still be an issue in some cases. Some browsers also only implement certain features on certain platforms, either temporarily or indefinitely.

I have in the past also seen some rendering issues that were apparently bugs in the browser itself only manifest on certain platforms.

So yes, in some edge-cases, and browser may have issues displaying a webpage as intended based on the host OS. The only way to be 100% sure is to test!

Comment: can we have any list that mentions all the differences you talking?

Comment: @Pdev I'm not aware of any projects attempting to list them all. There's probably too many to list, and each browser is a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. Webpages interact with operating systems in interesting ways and take settings from the operating system.

One bug in particular that I remember was on a page that had a drop-down list with 15-something options. In Chrome On Linux and Windows, everything was okay, but on OSX the browser would not display the scroll-bar in this drop-down list, just